# How to load file in app assets and file in vendor with same name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, spree

Hi I have two css file in different folder:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css
vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css
```

When I load `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'spree/frontend/all', media: 'screen' %>`, which `all.css` will be load?

How about one with `.scss`?

```
app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.scss
vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

App will look for the file in this way:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css
app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.scss
vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css
vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.scss
```

So `app` and `css` are more important than `vendor` and `scss`.

If you need to use the same file I guess it's better to change the name or dir and include it in the HEAD section.